# Unable to solve uncategorized SQLException when calling SQL Server using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am using JDBCTemplate to query a SQL server using:

> List results = jdbc.query(statement, new ResultDataMapper());

I have tried the statement in PreparedStatementCreator and String formats but neither work. I received the exception below:

> SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The statement did not return a result set.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.

My sql is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempSearch', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tempSearch;
CREATE TABLE #tempSearch
(
ID int,
Value VARCHAR(255)
)
INSERT INTO #tempSearch
VALUES(1,'?'),
(2,'?');
with cte as (
select RoleID,','+replace(replace(GroupNames,',',',,'),' ','')+',' GroupNames from UserGroup_Role_Mapping
)
,cte2 as(
select cte.RoleID, replace(cte.GroupNames,','+Value+',','') as GroupNames, s.ID, s.Value 
from cte
join #tempSearch s on ID=1
union all
select cte2.RoleID, replace(cte2.GroupNames,','+s.Value+',','') as l, s.ID ,s.Value
from cte2
join #tempSearch s on s.ID=cte2.ID+1
)
SELECT a.Role, a.Sort_Order, a.Parent, a.Parent_ID, a.Parent_URL, a.Child, a.Child_ID,a.Child_URL
FROM NC_View a 
WHERE a.Role IN (
Select Name from (
Select distinct RoleID from cte2 where len(GroupNames)=0
) tempRoles
join User_Role
on tempRoles.RoleID = User_Role.ID
)
DROP TABLE #tempSearch
```

I know the SQL works fine but i just cant get over the hump of calling it from JDBC. I have the Mapper and extractor all done too.

I ran this with a PreparedStatementCreator and String:

1. when i use PreparedstatementCreator and try to set 2 variables I get index out range errors "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range.":
   PreparedStatementCreator returnValue = new PreparedStatementCreator() {
           @Override
           public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
   sql.append("("+x +",'" + "?" +"'),"); //when constructing the sql
   PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
   statement.setString(z++, group); //when setting those values

   I am not sure why this is?  is the syntax incorrect? It seems it is not detecting the set?
   from debug i also see:
   Unable to translate SQLException with Error code '0'

   2. If I use String straight out i get:

      > org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [
      >   SQL FROM ABOVE - I TESTED AND IT WORKS
      >   ]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The statement did not return a result set.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.

I am not sure if the SQL is too complex or what. But also confused how using PreparedStatementCreator it wasnt detecting the ? to set variables... I am running out of ideas. I tried Multiqueries=true too

If I use SET NOCOUNT ON i get a different error:
Unable to solve uncategorized SQLException when calling SQL Server using JDBC

So i am bit confused too. I am not inserting a lot of data so maybe it doesn't matter?

Thanks!

Comment: At line 7 of your posted code, shouldn't the end of `create table` have a *closing* instead of *opening* perenthesis?

Comment: I updated and now i get a different error:
SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The statement did not return a result set.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.

I know it sounds obvious but i am certain it should return something.

Another curious thing is when i use Preparedstatement and try to set 2 variables I get index out range errors:

sql.append("("+x +",'" + "?" +"'),"); //when constructing the sql
statement.setString(z++, group); //when setting those values

Comment: Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the beginning of your SQL text.

Comment: Is it cause of the error? It seems error is result set 0?

Comment: You aren't executing a statement, you are executing a script, which can have multiple results. If NOCOUNT is off, you get an update count of the insert (and possibly the drop and create) before you get a result set of the select statement.

Comment: I tried but got "Unable to solve uncategorized SQLException when calling SQL Server using JDBC"

I also got different error "SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The statement did not return a result set.;"   without it.